# PyQt Dual Purpose ENTER Key Press

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, enter, qcombobox

I’m using PyQt5 and Python 3.6.  I want to use the `ENTER` (or `RETURN`) key for dual purposes.

If the user enters text into the combo box and then hits the `ENTER` key, then I want the text from the combo box to be appended to a list.  In all other situations, I want the `ENTER` key to serve as a shortcut for a push button.

I can’t find the correct decision for how the handle when `ENTER` is pressed.  Here is a code sample.  I’m looking to a decision in the `returnDecision(self)` function (toward the bottom of the script).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence   
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.initUI()        

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)        
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.move(100, 50)               
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btnPrint)
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox.move(100, 150)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QSize(150, 0))
        self.comboBox.setEditText("Initial Text")
        self.comboBox.editTextChanged.connect(self.cboxPrint)
        enter = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Return), self)
        enter.activated.connect(self.returnDecision)
        self.textList = []
        self.show()

    def btnPrint(self):
        print("Button was pressed")

    def btnAction(self):
        print("RETURN pressed when NOT editing combo box")
        self.btnPrint()

    def cboxPrint(self):
        print(self.comboBox.currentText())

    def cboxAction(self):
        print("RETURN pressed when editing combo box")
        self.textList.append(self.comboBox.currentText())
        print(self.textList)        

    def returnDecision(self):
        if ENTER KEY WAS PRESSED WHILE EDITING COMBO BOX:
            self.cboxAction()
        else:
            self.btnAction()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a custom subclass of the QComboBox and override the keyPressEvent method.  Then also implement a keyPressEvent in your widget and handle each differently.

```
class CustomCombo(QtWidgets.QComboBox):

    enter_pressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.enter_pressed.emit()
        else:
            QtWidgets.QComboBox.keyPressEvent(self, event)  
            # if the key is not return, handle normally


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # Code here
        self.combo_box = CustomCombo(self)
        self.combo_box.enter_pressed.connect(self.cboxAction)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.btnAction()
```

Comment: I like your idea of a custom subclass, but I'm having difficulties implementing it. I defined `comboBox` in 'Example' and tried but can't seem to pass the signal to the `CustomCombo` class. I tried `self.comboBox.editTextChanged.connect(self.combo_box(Qt.SIGNAL("pressed()")))`, but it appears that dynamically assigned signals are not permitted beginning in PyQt5. I can connect the key press signal to another method within `ComboBox`, but the when pressing the RETURN key, `Qt.Key_Return` is always intercepted `self.keyPressEvent()` within `Example` (instead of `CustomCombo`). Suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to pass the signal from your Example class to the CustomCombo class?  Aren't `self.cboxAction` and `self.btnAction` defined in the Example class?  If so, you will need the signal to go from the CustomCombo class to the Example class, which is what my answer does.

Comment: OK.  You are right.  Still stumbling through inheritance, super, subclasses, etc.  But I think I have it (for now).  Still one problem - the `CustomCombo(QComboBox)` widget isn't displaying in the main window with `self.show()` - only the button shows.  If I add `self.combo_box.show()`, the widget shows in a different window, but otherwise works as it should. I implemented `CustomCombo(QComboBox)` exactly as you wrote it.  I have `self.combo_box = CustomCombo()` in Example's `initUI(self)`, followed by its initializing (size, geometry, etc.).  How do I make the CustomCombo widget display?

Comment: Sorry, I set my tests initialization up differently than yours.  In your case you will need to set the CustomCombo class to take a parent argument and supply it to the QComboBox super call.  Then in your Example class when you define self.comboBox supply an instance of self to it. `self.comboBox = CustomCombo(self)`.  I have edited my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: That works!  I felt it had to be something associated with inheritances.